# In html how do you add an additional, non-submitting, button in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In html how do you add an additional button with a on-bound jquery click event attached to it inside a form that doesnt submit when pressed? Adding return false to the end of the triggered function doesnt seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add type="button" to the button then it will change from the default type of "submit" to "button" and it shouldnt post your form!

```
<form>
   <button type="button">Additional button</button>
   <input type="submit" value="Press to submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This works and i guess you were first, although the other answer was useful, too! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simply make an `<input type="button">`, instead of `<input type="submit">`.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ADeue/.

The important part: `<input type="button" value="Press me. I will not submit" onclick="exampleFunction();" />`.

Comment: thanks, i have upvoted this as i already accepted the other answer!